# Polynomial factorization, algebra

Tags: polynomials

I always get to a point where I can't find the answer cause I don't figure out any other ways to solve it. Please, tell me methods to calculate my moves before starting to solve a polynomial factorization.

This is the problem:

$4a^{4}-a^{2}+2a-1$

The answer is:
$(2a^{2}+a-1)(2a^{2}-a+1)$

How to solve and how to calculate my steps before solving? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(a) = 4a^4-a^2+2a-1$

First step to trying to factorise polynomials is to "guess" potential roots i.e. finding a value of $a$ such that $f(a)=0$

Usually we try some basic values of $a$ e.g. $0,1,-1$ etc...

In this case we see that $f(-1)=0$

Also notice that $f(\frac{1}{2})=0$

Then we can factorise as follows $f(a) = (a-\frac{1}{2})(a+1)g(a)$

where $g(a)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ which we should find. So let $g(a) = ba^2+ca+d$, then:

$f(a) = (a-\frac{1}{2})(a+1)(ba^2+ca+d)=0$

So we can expand this expression to get:

$f(a)= ba^4+(c+\frac{b}{2})a^3+(d+\frac{c-b}{2})a^2+\frac{d-c}{2}a-\frac{d}{2}=4a^4-a^2+2a-1=0$

Comparing coefficients:

$a^4:\quad b=4$

$a^3:\quad c+\frac{b}{2} =c+2=0\implies c=-2$

$a^2:\quad d+\frac{c-b}{2}=d-3=-1\implies d=2$

Then we have $f(a) = (a-\frac{1}{2})(a+1)(4a^2-2a+2)=(2a-1)(a+1)(2a^2-a+1)$

$f(a) = (2a^2+a-1)(2a^2-a+1)$

Comment: `Usually we try some basic values` Rather, by the rational root theorem, we try rationals of the form $p/q$ where $p=\pm 1$ and $q \mid 4\,$.

Answer (score 4):

$$4a^4 - (a^2-2a+1)$$
$$4a^4-(a-1)^2$$
$$(2a^2-a+1)(2a^2+a-1)$$

Done?

Comment: Wow, so fast resolution, I understood what you did, but how you made it so fast? How did you calculate your steps?

Comment: I've seen worse. So this one seemed easier. Moreover i spotted that $(a-1)^2$ hidden in disguise. This made it easier @NicolasLeskiu

Answer (score 1):

Alternative hint (if you don't see the difference of squares offhand): look for rational roots using the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which will find $x=-1,\frac{1}{2}$ as roots. Then factor out $(x+1)(x-\frac{1}{2})\,$ (or $(x+1)(2x-1)$ to simplify the calculations) and determine the remaining quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

For factorization of a polynomial, first you need to find the suitable, in most cases, 2-2 or 3-1 combinations of terms which makes a clue and has a close form expressions. For instance, in your question, you can use the 3-1 rule to use three terms which has a closed form $(a-1)^2$:

$$4a^{4}-a^{2}+2a-1 = 4a^{4}-(a^{2}-2a+1) = 4a^{4}-(a-1)^2 = (2a^{2}+a-1)(2a^{2}-a+1).$$

Also by 2-2 rule you have:

$$4a^{4}-a^{2}+2a-1 = (4a^{4}-a^{2})+(2a-1) = a^2(2a-1)(2a+1) +(2a-1)= (2a-1)(2a^3+a^2+1)= (2a-1)(a^3+a^2+a^3+1)= (2a-1)[a^2(a+1)+(a+1)(a^2-a+1))=(2a-1)(a+1)(2a^2-a+1).$$

where $$a^3+1 = (a+1)(a^2-a+1).$$

Comment: @dxiv: thanks for your nice comment.